# React no me da errores, pero no renderiza

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Estoy empezando con react e intentando hacer un clon de la pagina de tesla siguiendo un tutorial, pero no me renderiza absolutamente nada, me sale la pantalla en blanco, y tampoco me lanza ningun error, no se porque puede ser. Os dejo el repositorio a ver si alguno me puede ayudar con este error. [Repositorio](https://github.com/PabloFdez21/Tesla-React)

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que no hay errores en la terminal o en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Al igual que @Jacobo me interesa saber si recibes algún error en la consola del navegador, eso nos ayudaría mucho.

Comment: @Jacobo https://ibb.co/f0pPNWr estos son los errores que me dan, todos parecen estar relacionados con la biblioteca, por lo tanto debe ser algun error con como funciona mi codigo, lo cual me parece raro porque he seguido el tutorial paso a paso y no habia problema y tampoco se que tipo de error puede ser, porque como he dicho soy muy novato y no acabo de entenderlo, Gracias

Comment: @Pablo Fdez revisa esta publicación similar a tu problema [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663785/invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-com) para ver si te funciona igual estoy revisando el código, según esa publicación esta relacionado a la forma en que utilizaste los Hooks